# How to use KnockoutJS with Observable nested array?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

i'm new to knockoutJs, and now i've got a problem, my code is here:

**ViewModel:**

```
var projectModel = {
dateProject: ko.observableArray()
};

ko.applyBindings(projectModel, document.getElementById('projectShow'));
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="projectShow">
    <!-- ko foreach: dateProject -->
    <span data-bind="text:createDay"></span>
    <ul>
        <!-- ko foreach: projectList -->
        <li>
        </li>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>

<a id="add" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_self">an button</a>
```

**A click event**

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    projectModel.dateProject().length = 0;
    var projectItems = [
        {
            createDay:'2014/03/16',
            projectList:[
                {   
                    checkResult: "good",
                    labelArr: ['hello','world']
                },{ 
                    checkResult: "general",
                    labelArr: ['hi','world']
                }
            ]
        },{
            createDay:'2014/03/17',
            projectList:[
                {   
                    checkResult: "good",
                    labelArr: ['hello','world']
                },{ 
                    checkResult: "general",
                    labelArr: ['hi','world']
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

    foreach(var i = 0;i<projectItems.length;i++){
        projectModel.dateProject().push(projectItems[i])
    }
});
```

When the click event is trigger, i clear the model's root array(observableArray), and push some new items to it, but the ui doesn't update automatically, can anybody tell me what's problem with the code? Perhaps knockout-mapping-plugin can solve this problem, but i don't know how.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some little mistakes you have like syntax of forloop is wrong and to clear root array use removeAll function.
it should be like:-

```
projectModel.dateProject.removeAll();//clear root array
for(var i = 0;i<projectItems.length;i++){
    projectModel.dateProject.push(projectItems[i]) //don't use  '()'  with projectModel.dateProject
}
```

Add data-binding for nested observable array in view.

```
<div id="projectShow">
  <!-- ko foreach: dateProject -->
   <span data-bind="text:createDay"></span>
   <ul>
     <!-- ko foreach: projectList -->
       <li data-bind="text:checkResult"></li>
       <li data-bind="text:labelArr"></li>
     <!-- /ko -->
  </ul>
 <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/beLQ7/3/)

Comment: don't know why there is a negative voting, your answer is right,i've vote for you. But i'm confused, the official document said knockout array can be access with '()'.

Comment: You are right its value can be accessed with () but when you using some method over observableArray, parentheses is not needed.